# Is it possible to use tell-don't-ask pattern from outside the actor system?

Tags: akka

I have a service which is outside the actor system which makes a call to the actor system via ask and expects a response back.

An obvious approach for implementing this would be to use
Ask pattern and wait for the response until timeout happens, something like this:

```
val futureArticle = articleParseActor ? ParseArticle("someArctile")
val parsedArticle = Await.result(futureArticle, 10 seconds)
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with tell(!) from outside the actor system?

Comment: Could you clarify about why you don't want to use ask? The whole point of ask versus tell is whether you want a response (as Vadim's answer points out). Explaining why you want to avoid ask might help someone provide an alternative.

Comment: Not answering your question, but sounds like a use case for akka-streams to me.

Comment: @MarkusRother could you give some insights on how it would fit the akka-streams use case?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the method signature.

```
final def tell(msg: Any, sender: ActorRef): Unit
```

Tell method returns Unit. It means that you are not able to receive Future as you can in ask method.

```
def ask(message: Any)(implicit timeout: Timeout, sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[Any]
```

If you want to receive some message using tell than probably you need to implement some custom ReceiverActor then it will receive message inside actor system and then it will call outside actor logic. Also, you can implement something more general and probably it will be similar to the ask method.